# Ivy doesn't find my artifact in filesystem

Tags: ivy, dependency-management

I've got an artifact in my local filesystem, but Ivy doesn't resolve it unless I put the <filesystem> resolver inside a <chain>. And it renames the artifact extension when it resolves it.

Here's my ivy.xml:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="apache" module="hello-ivy"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="myorg" name="mymodule" rev="1.1-SNAPSHOT"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

And here's my ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings />

  <resolvers>
      <filesystem name="local">
        <artifact pattern="/path/to/my/artifact/[module]/dist/[module]-[revision].zip" />
      </filesystem>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

My build.xml:

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="hello-ivy" default="deps">

  <target name="deps" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
    <ivy:resolve />
    <ivy:retrieve />
  </target>
</project>
```

The artifact is a .zip file. It's in the right place and named correctly (in accordance with the <artifact>'s pattern attribute. But when I run ant, it fails to resolve the artifact:

```
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: myorg#mymodule;1.1-SNAPSHOT: no resolver found for myorg#mymodule: check your configuration
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:resolve]   unknown resolver null
[ivy:resolve]   no resolver found for myorg#mymodule: check your configuration
```

Why doesn't it find my module?

Then: if I put the <filesystem> element inside a <chain> element, it resolves:

```
[ivy:resolve]   found myorg#mymodule;1.1-SNAPSHOT in local
[ivy:resolve] downloading /path/to/my/artifact/mymodule/dist/mymodule-1.1-SNAPSHOT.zip 
[ivy:resolve] ..................(lots of dots here).....(37899kB)
[ivy:resolve]   [SUCCESSFUL ] myorg#mymodule;1.1-SNAPSHOT!mymodule.jar (430ms)
```

So that's strange. Why did the <chain> make a difference?
And BTW, why is my module now a JAR??? The source is a ZIP file, I swear. It's the right one, too - I just rebuilt the ZIP, and the latest changes are in my JAR file. Why did Ivy rename it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default [type of an artifact in ivy is jar and the default extension is jar, too.](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency-artifact.html)
This will lead to the renaming.

You have to define your dependency like this (explicitly define the artifact):

```
<dependency org="myorg" name="mymodule" rev="1.1-SNAPSHOT">
  <artifact name="mymodule" type="zip" conf="A,B"/>
</dependency>
```

But you have to define the filesystem resolver properly:

```
  <filesystem name="local">
    <artifact pattern="/path/to/my/artifact/[module]/dist/[module]-[revision].[ext]" />
  </filesystem>
```

The best approach would be to define a proper ivy.xml for your special dependency, which clearly defines what artifacts are available. And put this in your dist folder.

See:

- https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/publications.html
- https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/artifact.html

And it is often a good idea to run ant with `ant -v` when debugging ivy. This will give great additional infos.

Comment: Thanks @oers, that explains why my ZIP became a JAR; if I put the <artifact> element there, I get my ZIP. Any idea about the other part - i.e. why the <chain> element is necessary?

Comment: @ladlestein nope, it should work without. Did you try again with your new settings?

Comment: @ladlestein To avoid chain resolver, try specifiying a **defaultResolver="local"** attribute in the *settings* tag: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/settings.html

Comment: @oers I did try again, with the same result - now I get a ZIP file, but only if I put the <chain> there.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor that worked - it resolved without the <chain>. Why does that work? Is the defaultResolver mandatory unless you have a <chain> resolver? Or is there something peculiar about my setup?

Comment: @Ladlestein could you turn this into a new question? Seems quite interesting and would avoid discussion in comments.